# SSE vector Operation on type double

Tags: c++, c, sse, simd

I want to use SIMD Operation of vectors containing double type values on AMD64 architecture. below is the simple example of my Problem. this works fine if I print float values , but not for double. I Need precision of upto 9 decimal Digits.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<emmintrin.h>

typedef union f4vector
{
  __m128d v;
}float4;

int main()
{
float4 x,y,z;
 double  f0[2]={2334, 5};
  double  f1[2]={2334.32345324 , 5};
 double f3[2];

x.v=_mm_set_pd(f0[0], f0[1]);
y.v = _mm_set_pd(f1[0], f1[1]);
z.v = _mm_mul_pd(x.v , y.v);

f3[0]=z.v[0];
f3[1]=z.v[1];

printf("%d, %d\n", f3[0], f3[1]);  // doesnt print correct values.

}
```

Comment: The `%d` format specifier is for integers. If you wan't to print float or doubles, use `%f`.

Comment: Beyond the obvious mistakes, with constant values, an optimizer will chew through this and pass constants to `printf`. There won't be any SIMD operations going on here at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes:

1. Using %d format specifier instead of %f in function printf.
2. To use SIMD instructions effective you have to load and store data with using of vector instructions such as _mm_loadu_pd/_mm_storeu_pd. Intrinsic _mm_set_pd is very ineffecient.

Below I write correct example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<emmintrin.h>

int main()
{
    double d0[2] = { 2334, 5 };
    double d1[2] = { 2334.32345324 , 5 };
    double d2[2] = { 0, 0 };

    __m128d v0 = _mm_loadu_pd(d0);
    __m128d v1 = _mm_loadu_pd(d1);
    __m128d v2 = _mm_mul_pd(v0, v1);
    _mm_storeu_pd(d2, v2);

    printf("%f, %f\n", d2[0], d2[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
5448310.939862, 25.000000
```

Comment: Better that you *explain* what the mistakes are!

Answer (score 0):

In printf you have used format specifier as %d you need to use %f as you want to print double value